# Convert JSON to SQL row

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have this below JSON and I would like to load them to my MSSQL table

```
 [{"Item_name": ["Lizinka", "L4690.S53", "Alder Pebble Grain Leather Boot w/ Walking Sole", "Becketts Oxford", "Phillip II Oxford", "Helston Moc Toe Boot", "Croft Pebble Grain Leather Derby w/ Walking Sole", "Croft Pebble Grain Leather Derby w/ Walking Sole", "City II Cap Toe Oxford", "Loe Museum Calf Derby w/ Classic Rubber Sole", "Trent Museum Calf Oxford w/ Single Leather Sole", "Lopez Loafer", "Lopez Loafer", "Lopez Loafer", "E000030", "E000037", "L1409.74", "L1454.74", "E000051", "I900068", "EU00048", "E070005", "Arizona Boot", "IU90054", "PS29238", "I980008", "Suede Over the Knee Boot", "E050000", "I900005", "A87280-MFN796", "RU90068", "EU00042", "E970021A", "E000027", "IU90012", "Wren Cap Toe Oxford", "Adley Loafer", "L4723", "Olympus Mons EVO", "IU90028", "Harmony Sparkle Rhinestone Chain Strap Heel Sandal", "EU00023", "May London High Top Embroidered Sneaker", "E000015", "E050006", "I900029", "RU90007", "Ciconia 70", "Tolk", "RU90059", "Cassapara Reversed Leather Gum Sole Chelsea", "PS33085A", "Joan", "Joan", "Holme Monk Sneaker", "Lewis Slant Zip Boot", "I970023", "Kenneth Cap Toe Oxford", "PS31108", "Fox Loafer", "Lesley 75", "Lesley 75", "RS00020", "EU00030", "RS00031", "EU00043", "E000053", "RM00018", "Soraya", "Pull-On Boot", "PS34045A", "Tyne Loafer", "RU90026A", "Burwood Oxford", "Brooklyn Chi Sneaker", "Susanne", "Benta", "Kay", "Benta", "G2 SM", "EU00017", "RM00031", "E050001", "RU90026", "Liberty & Justice", "Blowout", "Selena Crystal", "Selena Crystal", "Harmony Heel Sandal", "I900037", "RU90055", "Kali", "Evett Sneaker", "Danzey Boot", "Danzey Boot", "Dolly Platform Pump", "D-Bumpy One Sneaker", "Fiandra Intrecciato Loafer", "I950005", "Lugosi"], "Item_price": ["$4,330.00", "$2,339.96", "$2,000.00", "$1,910.00", "$1,910.00", "$1,630.00", "$1,615.00", "$1,615.00", "$1,490.00", "$1,490.00", "$1,490.00", "$1,450.00", "$1,450.00", "$1,450.00", "$1,450.00", "$1,450.00", "$1,435.96", "$1,435.96", "$1,350.00", "$1,299.97", "$1,295.00", "$1,295.00", "$1,240.00", "$1,195.00", "$1,185.99", "$1,165.50", "$1,161.00", "$1,150.00", "$1,125.00", "$1,100.00", "$1,095.00", "$1,095.00", "$1,095.00", "$1,095.00", "$1,095.00", "$1,040.00", "$1,040.00", "$1,035.96", "$999.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$995.00", "$975.00", "$950.00", "$948.00", "$935.00", "$930.00", "$930.00", "$920.00", "$898.00", "$897.00", "$895.99", "$895.99", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$895.00", "$885.00", "$880.00", "$875.00", "$865.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$850.00", "$849.95", "$849.95", "$845.00", "$845.00", "$845.00", "$845.00", "$825.00", "$825.00", "$820.00", "$820.00", "$820.00", "$815.00", "$810.00", "$810.00", "$805.00", "$800.00"], "Item_brandname": ["Salvatore Ferragamo", "Lucchese", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Lucchese", "Lucchese", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "DSQUARED2", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Proenza Schouler", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "MARNI", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Sergio Rossi", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "Lucchese", "La Sportiva", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Marsell", "Proenza Schouler", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "John Lobb", "John Varvatos Collection", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Santoni", "Proenza Schouler", "Santoni", "Stuart Weitzman", "Stuart Weitzman", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Rupert Sanderson", "Gravati", "Proenza Schouler", "John Lobb", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Church's", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Alexandre Birman", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Alexandre Birman", "La Sportiva", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Tabitha Simmons", "Tabitha Simmons", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Tabitha Simmons", "John Lobb", "Church's", "Church's", "Charlotte Olympia", "DSQUARED2", "Bottega Veneta", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Jeffery-West"]},
    {"Item_name": ["Leather Ankle Boot", "Ammunition", "Tieland Over the Knee Boot", "Lowland Over the Knee Boot", "Lowland Over the Knee Boot", "Lowland Over the Knee Boot", "Tieland Over the Knee Boot", "Lewis Buckle Chelsea Boot", "RU70009N", "Betty Platform Sandal", "Kali Bis", "RW90066", "RW90055", "Kali Bis", "Leni Crystal", "Patton", "Kali Bis", "Xaren", "Xamira", "Cimbra Sneaker", "Monica", "Lesley 75", "Urchin Sneaker", "Urchin Sneaker", "Betty Platform Sandal", "Monica", "Osimo Pump", "RW70009A", "Lida SW", "Aicha", "Aicha", "Rachel", "Sherman Loafer", "Stanford Oxford", "Chiara Embroidery Sandal", "EU00038", "RS00019", "RM00042", "I700055A", "E000024", "I900056", "E000034", "Rachel Bootie", "Vicky Boot 50", "IU90035", "Ketsby Boot", "Monmouth Boot", "Consul 173 Oxford", "RW90069", "Celina 2", "SR1", "PS33095A", "Round Up Rosie", "Round Up Rosie", "Savanna", "Knit Paisley Sneaker", "Ravello Block Heel Sandal", "Meadow Printed Croc", "Cross Strap Boot", "Mountain Lace-Up Boot", "Consul Oxford", "Gardena", "Soft Sneaker", "SR1 Sandal", "Double Sketch Low Top Sneaker", "Asten Loafer", "A87300-MFN802", "Sidney Loafer", "RS00044", "E000022A", "E000049", "E000032", "Spantik", "Mercantile Makeshifter", "Almost Famous", "Hermione", "Tippie Pump", "Levah Sneaker", "Levah Sneaker", "Deirde", "Levah Sneaker", "Ortensia 55", "Belshaw Patent Oxford", "Haven Suede Slip-On Sneaker", "Swing", "Jessa 95 mm Rectangle Hard", "Kyoto", "Wayne", "Amatea 70", "Emilia Sling Back", "RW90017", "Dodger II Slip-On Sneaker", "May London Mid Top Zayn Sneaker", "I970049", "L4625", "90 mm Boot", "Eldridge Harness Boot", "Morrison Sharpei Boot", "Morrison Sharpei Boot", "Fleetwood Lace Boot"], "Item_price": ["$800.00", "$799.95", "$798.00", "$798.00", "$798.00", "$798.00", "$798.00", "$798.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$795.00", "$790.00", "$790.00", "$790.00", "$787.50", "$775.00", "$775.00", "$775.00", "$774.95", "$774.95", "$765.00", "$760.00", "$760.00", "$760.00", "$755.99", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$750.00", "$749.95", "$749.95", "$745.00", "$740.00", "$735.00", "$735.00", "$735.00", "$735.00", "$730.00", "$730.00", "$730.00", "$729.27", "$728.00", "$725.00", "$715.99", "$715.30", "$715.00", "$711.75", "$710.00", "$710.00", "$700.00", "$699.96", "$698.00", "$698.00", "$698.00", "$698.00", "$698.00"], "Item_brandname": ["Gravati", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Stuart Weitzman", "Stuart Weitzman", "Stuart Weitzman", "Stuart Weitzman", "Stuart Weitzman", "John Varvatos Collection", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Tabitha Simmons", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Tabitha Simmons", "Tabitha Simmons", "Tabitha Simmons", "Tabitha Simmons", "Pedro Garcia", "Pedro Garcia", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Sergio Rossi", "Stuart Weitzman", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Sergio Rossi", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Clergerie", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Sophia Webster", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Alexandre Birman", "Alexandre Birman", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Church's", "Church's", "Church's", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Clergerie", "Sergio Rossi", "Proenza Schouler", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Rupert Sanderson", "Etro", "Bottega Veneta", "Rupert Sanderson", "Gravati", "Santoni", "Church's", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Sergio Rossi", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Sergio Rossi", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "La Sportiva", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo", "Tabitha Simmons", "Bottega Veneta", "John Lobb", "John Lobb", "Rupert Sanderson", "John Lobb", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "John Lobb", "Tabitha Simmons", "Tory Burch", "Rupert Sanderson", "Clergerie", "Salvatore Ferragamo", "Charlotte Olympia", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Bottega Veneta", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Giuseppe Zanotti", "Lucchese", "Tory Burch", "John Varvatos Collection", "John Varvatos Collection", "John Varvatos Collection", "John Varvatos Collection"]}]
```

below is the output I am looking for.

```
"Item_name","Item_price","Item_brandname"
"Lizinka","$4,330.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"L4690.S53","$2,339.96","Lucchese"
"Alder Pebble Grain Leather Boot w/ Walking Sole","$2,000.00","John Lobb"
"Becketts Oxford","$1,910.00","John Lobb"
"Phillip II Oxford","$1,910.00","John Lobb"
"Helston Moc Toe Boot","$1,630.00","John Lobb"
"Croft Pebble Grain Leather Derby w/ Walking Sole","$1,615.00","John Lobb"
"Croft Pebble Grain Leather Derby w/ Walking Sole","$1,615.00","John Lobb"
"City II Cap Toe Oxford","$1,490.00","John Lobb"
"Loe Museum Calf Derby w/ Classic Rubber Sole","$1,490.00","John Lobb"
"Trent Museum Calf Oxford w/ Single Leather Sole","$1,490.00","John Lobb"
"Lopez Loafer","$1,450.00","John Lobb"
"Lopez Loafer","$1,450.00","John Lobb"
"Lopez Loafer","$1,450.00","John Lobb"
"E000030","$1,450.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000037","$1,450.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"L1409.74","$1,435.96","Lucchese"
"L1454.74","$1,435.96","Lucchese"
"E000051","$1,350.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I900068","$1,299.97","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"EU00048","$1,295.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E070005","$1,295.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Arizona Boot","$1,240.00","DSQUARED2"
"IU90054","$1,195.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"PS29238","$1,185.99","Proenza Schouler"
"I980008","$1,165.50","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Suede Over the Knee Boot","$1,161.00","MARNI"
"E050000","$1,150.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I900005","$1,125.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"A87280-MFN796","$1,100.00","Sergio Rossi"
"RU90068","$1,095.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"EU00042","$1,095.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E970021A","$1,095.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000027","$1,095.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"IU90012","$1,095.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Wren Cap Toe Oxford","$1,040.00","John Lobb"
"Adley Loafer","$1,040.00","John Lobb"
"L4723","$1,035.96","Lucchese"
"Olympus Mons EVO","$999.00","La Sportiva"
"IU90028","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Harmony Sparkle Rhinestone Chain Strap Heel Sandal","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"EU00023","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"May London High Top Embroidered Sneaker","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000015","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E050006","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I900029","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RU90007","$995.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Ciconia 70","$995.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Tolk","$975.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"RU90059","$950.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Cassapara Reversed Leather Gum Sole Chelsea","$948.00","Marsell"
"PS33085A","$935.00","Proenza Schouler"
"Joan","$930.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Joan","$930.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Holme Monk Sneaker","$920.00","John Lobb"
"Lewis Slant Zip Boot","$898.00","John Varvatos Collection"
"I970023","$897.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Kenneth Cap Toe Oxford","$895.99","Santoni"
"PS31108","$895.99","Proenza Schouler"
"Fox Loafer","$895.00","Santoni"
"Lesley 75","$895.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Lesley 75","$895.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"RS00020","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"EU00030","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RS00031","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"EU00043","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000053","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RM00018","$895.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Soraya","$885.00","Rupert Sanderson"
"Pull-On Boot","$880.00","Gravati"
"PS34045A","$875.00","Proenza Schouler"
"Tyne Loafer","$865.00","John Lobb"
"RU90026A","$850.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Burwood Oxford","$850.00","Church's"
"Brooklyn Chi Sneaker","$850.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Susanne","$850.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Benta","$850.00","Alexandre Birman"
"Kay","$850.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Benta","$850.00","Alexandre Birman"
"G2 SM","$850.00","La Sportiva"
"EU00017","$850.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RM00031","$850.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E050001","$850.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RU90026","$850.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Liberty & Justice","$849.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Blowout","$849.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Selena Crystal","$845.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Selena Crystal","$845.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Harmony Heel Sandal","$845.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I900037","$845.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RU90055","$825.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Kali","$825.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Evett Sneaker","$820.00","John Lobb"
"Danzey Boot","$820.00","Church's"
"Danzey Boot","$820.00","Church's"
"Dolly Platform Pump","$815.00","Charlotte Olympia"
"D-Bumpy One Sneaker","$810.00","DSQUARED2"
"Fiandra Intrecciato Loafer","$810.00","Bottega Veneta"
"I950005","$805.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Lugosi","$800.00","Jeffery-West"
"Leather Ankle Boot","$800.00","Gravati"
"Ammunition","$799.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Tieland Over the Knee Boot","$798.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Lowland Over the Knee Boot","$798.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Lowland Over the Knee Boot","$798.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Lowland Over the Knee Boot","$798.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Tieland Over the Knee Boot","$798.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Lewis Buckle Chelsea Boot","$798.00","John Varvatos Collection"
"RU70009N","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Betty Platform Sandal","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Kali Bis","$795.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"RW90066","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RW90055","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Kali Bis","$795.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Leni Crystal","$795.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Patton","$795.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Kali Bis","$795.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Xaren","$795.00","Pedro Garcia"
"Xamira","$795.00","Pedro Garcia"
"Cimbra Sneaker","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Monica","$795.00","Sergio Rossi"
"Lesley 75","$795.00","Stuart Weitzman"
"Urchin Sneaker","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Urchin Sneaker","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Betty Platform Sandal","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Monica","$795.00","Sergio Rossi"
"Osimo Pump","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"RW70009A","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Lida SW","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Aicha","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Aicha","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Rachel","$795.00","Clergerie"
"Sherman Loafer","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Stanford Oxford","$795.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Chiara Embroidery Sandal","$795.00","Sophia Webster"
"EU00038","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RS00019","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"RM00042","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I700055A","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000024","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I900056","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000034","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Rachel Bootie","$795.00","Alexandre Birman"
"Vicky Boot 50","$795.00","Alexandre Birman"
"IU90035","$795.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Ketsby Boot","$790.00","Church's"
"Monmouth Boot","$790.00","Church's"
"Consul 173 Oxford","$790.00","Church's"
"RW90069","$787.50","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Celina 2","$775.00","Clergerie"
"SR1","$775.00","Sergio Rossi"
"PS33095A","$775.00","Proenza Schouler"
"Round Up Rosie","$774.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Round Up Rosie","$774.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Savanna","$765.00","Rupert Sanderson"
"Knit Paisley Sneaker","$760.00","Etro"
"Ravello Block Heel Sandal","$760.00","Bottega Veneta"
"Meadow Printed Croc","$760.00","Rupert Sanderson"
"Cross Strap Boot","$755.99","Gravati"
"Mountain Lace-Up Boot","$750.00","Santoni"
"Consul Oxford","$750.00","Church's"
"Gardena","$750.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Soft Sneaker","$750.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"SR1 Sandal","$750.00","Sergio Rossi"
"Double Sketch Low Top Sneaker","$750.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Asten Loafer","$750.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"A87300-MFN802","$750.00","Sergio Rossi"
"Sidney Loafer","$750.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"RS00044","$750.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000022A","$750.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000049","$750.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"E000032","$750.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Spantik","$750.00","La Sportiva"
"Mercantile Makeshifter","$749.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Almost Famous","$749.95","Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo"
"Hermione","$745.00","Tabitha Simmons"
"Tippie Pump","$740.00","Bottega Veneta"
"Levah Sneaker","$735.00","John Lobb"
"Levah Sneaker","$735.00","John Lobb"
"Deirde","$735.00","Rupert Sanderson"
"Levah Sneaker","$735.00","John Lobb"
"Ortensia 55","$730.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Belshaw Patent Oxford","$730.00","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Haven Suede Slip-On Sneaker","$730.00","John Lobb"
"Swing","$729.27","Tabitha Simmons"
"Jessa 95 mm Rectangle Hard","$728.00","Tory Burch"
"Kyoto","$725.00","Rupert Sanderson"
"Wayne","$715.99","Clergerie"
"Amatea 70","$715.30","Salvatore Ferragamo"
"Emilia Sling Back","$715.00","Charlotte Olympia"
"RW90017","$711.75","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"Dodger II Slip-On Sneaker","$710.00","Bottega Veneta"
"May London Mid Top Zayn Sneaker","$710.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"I970049","$700.00","Giuseppe Zanotti"
"L4625","$699.96","Lucchese"
"90 mm Boot","$698.00","Tory Burch"
"Eldridge Harness Boot","$698.00","John Varvatos Collection"
"Morrison Sharpei Boot","$698.00","John Varvatos Collection"
"Morrison Sharpei Boot","$698.00","John Varvatos Collection"
"Fleetwood Lace Boot","$698.00","John Varvatos Collection"
```

I am using this code to push `JSON` to `SQL`

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(500)
    SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\abc\data.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

SELECT Item_Name
      ,Item_brandname
      ,Item_saleprice
FROM  
OPENJSON ( @JSON )  
WITH (        Item_Name nvarchar(50) '$.Item_Name'
      ,Item_brandname nvarchar(50) '$.Item_brandname'
      ,Item_saleprice nvarchar(50) '$.Item_saleprice'
 )
```

I get an error saying

```
    Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 12
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 493.
```

I tried using online JSON for-matters to check if my JSON is wrong but I get the same error
Not sure where exactly the issue is.

Updated the code to get the `JSON` as `SINGLE_CLOB`

Comment: `SET @json = 'C:\abc\data.json'`... The string `'C:\abc\data.json'` is clearly not valid JSON data. Are you expecting that `SET` to actually act like a streamreader and get the text from the file? That isn't how SQL works at all. `'C:\abc\data.json'` is a string (`varchar`) nothing else. It doesn't represent a file. SQL isn't a scripting language like Powershell.

Comment: The error is saying that `C:\abc\data.json` is invalid json and it doesn't know what to do with `C:`

Comment: OPENJSON expects not a file path, it expects json-string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu  I have updated the code to get the JSON and also updated the error.

Comment: What is the expected format of the data once it's in SQL? Simply using `SELECT BulkColumn
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\abc\data.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;` will show your json data in one column - the json you posted is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The input JSON contains nested JSON arrays, so you need to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema and additional `APPLY` operator for each nested array. The result from `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of JSON array, the `key` column holds the index of each item in this array.

JSON (simplified):

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
[
   {
      "Item_name":[
         "Lizinka",
         "L4690.S53",
         "Alder Pebble Grain Leather Boot w/ Walking Sole"
      ],
      "Item_price":[
         "$4,330.00",
         "$2,339.96",
         "$2,000.00"
      ],
      "Item_brandname":[
         "Salvatore Ferragamo",
         "Lucchese",
         "John Lobb"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Item_name":[
         "Leather Ankle Boot",
         "Ammunition",
         "Tieland Over the Knee Boot"
      ],
      "Item_price":[
         "$800.00",
         "$799.95",
         "$798.00"
      ],
      "Item_brandname":[
         "Gravati",
         "Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo",
         "Stuart Weitzman"
      ]
   }
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   j1.[value] AS Item_name,
   j2.[value] AS Item_price,
   j3.[value] AS Item_brandname
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j.[value], '$.Item_name') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j.[value], '$.Item_price') j2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j.[value], '$.Item_brandname') j3
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key] AND j2.[key] = j3.[key]
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item_name                                       Item_price  Item_brandname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lizinka                                         $4,330.00   Salvatore Ferragamo
L4690.S53                                       $2,339.96   Lucchese
Alder Pebble Grain Leather Boot w/ Walking Sole $2,000.00   John Lobb
Leather Ankle Boot                              $800.00     Gravati
Ammunition                                      $799.95     Double D Ranchwear by Old Gringo
Tieland Over the Knee Boot                      $798.00     Stuart Weitzman
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I get this error `Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 31
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 493.`

Comment: @RaghuParvatha The answer is updated with simplified JSON input. The JSON in the example is correct, you just need to escape `'` (`Church's`with `Church''s`) when you execute the script in the answer. Probably worng JSON is the reason for your error. Thanks..

Comment: I am not sure how to clean up the json because even when I try online formatters and clean it I have the same error

Comment: @RaghuParvatha How does this _wrong_ JSON look like?

Comment: it is same as the one I pasted above.

Comment: @RaghuParvatha It's strange. The JSON in the question is valid, just change the `Church's` with `Church''s` (to escape the `'`) if you want to test the statement in the answer in the SSMS for example.